# ¿Cómo solucionar el problema con el virtualenv de python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo un problema al usar un entorno virtual de python3, una vez activado, instalé con `pip django==2.0.7`, el problema es cuando importo a django y accedo a `django.__file__`, no me reconoce el que instalé, sino el que esta instalado en `/usr/lib/python3.6/django/__init__.py`, es decir que aunque este activo el entorno virtual, no reconoce los módulos instalados en el.

Comment: Una vez activado el entorno: El comando `which python` ¿qué retorna?

Comment: devuelve el path donde se encuentra el entorno virtual

Comment: y `pip freeze` te dice que tienes instalado `django==2.0.7`?

Comment: si, dice que esta instalado, sin embargo cuando lo importo me da la version 1.8 que esta, entra en un conflicto que no entiendo porque me dice que esta el 2.0.7 y a la hora de usar usa el 1.8

Comment: @LeandroL yo recomendaría que usarás Anaconda Navigator tiene un gestor de entornos virtuales el cual es más sencillo de usar.

Comment: estas usando algún IDE?